# Can I control power to one USB port?

Tags: usb, keyboard, power, backlight

I have a Microsoft Reclusa and I don't want the backlight on while I am not there. I want to turn the USB port's power off to stop the backlight at night. Is there any software that will do this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thread [here on whirlpool](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/845304.html) has a few suggestions.

Must suggestions revolve around the Windows Device Manager / Power Management settings.

A [command line tool called DevCon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) for the Device Manager looks the most promising

Results will vary depending on your computers motherboard.